# How can I create an empty dummy HttpResponse

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am using org.apache.http.HttpResponse

I want to create an empty dummy resposne, I am going to use this to return when errors occur instead of passing back null.

I tried to create one and it has lost of weird params.  Can someone tell me how to create one.

Comment: *"it has lost of weird params"* this is too vague. You need to clarify this more. Keep in mind: don't ignore errors, interpret them. They tell something about the cause. You know, once a cause is understood, the solution is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement `HttpResponse` with no-op methods.

Comment: on my system HttpServletResponse does not exist, only HttpResponse

Comment: Anyway, I implementd it and there are a whole lot of methods that need to be overridden.  Is it ok just to leave these blank.  When I call HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); I don't want an error to occur, I just want the stream to be an empty string

Comment: No code reviewer in my company will accept 5 screens of empty methods.

Answer (score 30):

Depending on what version of commons you're using, you might want to try [DefaultHttpResponseFactory](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/DefaultHttpResponseFactory.html). This is the way that the library creates some of it's responses internally so it may or may not serve your purposes.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponseFactory;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpResponseFactory;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine;

HttpResponseFactory factory = new DefaultHttpResponseFactory();
HttpResponse response = factory.newHttpResponse(new BasicStatusLine(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpStatus.SC_OK, null), null);
```

Comment: HOW TO ADD DATA IN THE HttpResponse Object

Comment: response.setEntity(entity);

Comment: Why not just use `new BasicHttpResponse(...)`?

Answer (score 2):

This version add the entity content and is a little bit more compact:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.TEXT_HTML;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

public static HttpResponse buildResponse(HttpStatus status, String text){
    
       HttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, status.value(), status.reasonPhrase);
       response.setEntity(new StringEntity(text, TEXT_HTML));
       return response;
    }
```

Note that I am using the Spring HttpStatus just for my convenience but may be changed with parameters

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, implementing a HttpServletResponse seems quite a lot work, and you'll be dependent on the actual Servlet implementation.

I think I'd use `request.getRequestDispatcher("/dummy.html").forward(request, response)`

Comment: He's talking about Apache Commons HttpClient, not about servlets. http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html By the way, on a servlet it would be easy, just don't touch the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that returns HttpResponse with the status code:

```
public HttpResponse<String> createDummyResponse(int statusCode) {
    return new HttpResponse<>() {
        @Override
        public int statusCode() {
            return statusCode;
        }

        @Override
        public HttpRequest request() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Optional<HttpResponse<String>> previousResponse() {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        @Override
        public HttpHeaders headers() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String body() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Optional<SSLSession> sslSession() {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        @Override
        public URI uri() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public HttpClient.Version version() {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Other attributes (e.g. body, etc.) you could pass as parameters to the method createDummyResponse.